# How to get a request object inside urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to use custom template on page_not_found default handle

Inside ***urls.py***

```
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

handler404 = page_not_found(request, None, "pages/custom/404.html")
```

*page_not found* method requires request, exception and template. So how can i get the request object. I know the alternative for using it inside views.py

Comment: There is no need to do this. Just put your 404.html in the base templates directory and it will be used automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `handler404` with a function, not return value of the function.

```
from functools import partial

handler404 = partial(page_not_found, template_name='pages/custom/404.html')
```